# Parsing php requires

Tags: php

This could be easy but I just can't seem to be able to figure it out for now. Lets assume we have two sets of .php files:

Set 1, that contains files named page1.php, page2.php, ... pageN.php.

Set 2, that contains files named module1, module2.php, ... moduleN.php.

Files from "Set 1" contain non-php code that should be treated as TEXT, and are using

```
<?php require("SomeFileFromSet2.php");?>
```

to include the respective contents from the files on Set 2. Files from set 1 are never php "required" by any other file.

Also, the files from "Set 2" can be required by one or more files from "Set 1", but can also "require" other files, from "Set 2" only. If SomeFileFromSet2.php is getting "required" from AnotherSet2File.php, then the first cannot also require the file it 's been required from (the latter), I mean there are not circular issues. (I could explain this (better?) using more sets of files, but tried to stick to two for simplicity). Files from Set 2 also contain non-php code to be treated as text again.

There is no other PHP code in none of the files of either set, except the

```
<?php require("SomeFileFromSet2.php");?>
```

calls.
What I want to achieve is to find a way and perform some kind of building process, so that when I run it for each file from "Set 1", I can parse php requires on it and on the modules that it includes, and get a new output file like "page1-with-modules.whatever" that would be php require "free" and contain all the code from the module files.

EDIT: Adding a basic sample so that I make more clear what I would like to achieve.

Contents of filefromset1.php (ie page1.php) could be:

```
<some no-php code #1>
<?php require("SomeFileFromSet2.php");?>
<some no-php code #2>
```

Contents of SomeFileFromSet2.php could be:

```
<some no-php code #3>
<?php require("SomeOTHERFileFromSet2.php");?>
<some no-php code #4>
```

And SomeOTHERFileFromSet2.php could have:

```
<some no-php code #5>
```

What I want to achieve is to parse all these requires in the files related to "filefromset1.php" and output a new "php-free" file containing:

```
<some no-php code #1>
<some no-php code #3>
<some no-php code #5>
<some no-php code #4>
<some no-php code #2>
```

Comment: http://php.net/require_once

Comment: This wouldn't help me achieve what I want, perhaps my explanation is not good enough.. I will try to add an example.

Comment: so instead of `<?php req(file1); req(file2) etc..`. you want something that'll "compile" your scripts into a single monolithic one, and you end up with `<?php contents of file1; contents of file2 etc..`?

Comment: Are you looking for [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)? What you wan't is not clear from your question.

Comment: What Marc B said..! I added an example to explain in the simplest way I could think of.

Comment: what are you parsing?

Comment: should make no difference my friend, since there is no <?php .... ;?> anywhere else everything else should be treated as text and be copied as is..!!

Comment: Why isn't this working for you? What error are you receiving?

Comment: I am not receiving any errors, what I need is a way to automate this process so that it can run on a file from set 1 and give me a new file for it, that would include the code from the required files in place of the require commands. Perhaps this is more tricky than I thought? I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it and it was pretty simple! Since I am currently on windows 10
I changed powershell's encoding to utf-8 by running 'chcp65001', and then I run the php.exe command like this:

```
path-to\php.exe ./page1.php >> page1-with-modules.html
```

The contents of page1-with-modules.html was exactly what I wanted to achieve for "page1".

Answer (score -1):

For what you are trying to do you cannot use include or require. Since you are wanting to generate new files you should be using fopen, fread, and fwrite.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it in PHP, you can also parse the AST using [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser).

If I recall correctly, it is also used in some well-known frameworks too (like Laravel).